# Downvote + Delete (e.g. when checking flags)

Tags: feature-request, flags, 10k-tools

When checking flags in the 10K tools, an answer with a negative score has a nice delete button next to it. If the answer is zero scored, I can cast a downvote to give it a negative score, which makes it eligible for deletion. However I need to open the full question to get to the delete link.

If I downvote an answer from the question view, I have to reload the question to get the delete link.

I would like the "delete" button to appear automatically, if my downvote makes the answer eligible for deletion.

For example, in this situation

[image]

Comment: I like this idea, I think it would help the community deal with flags and free up moderator time.